# jQuery UI tabs: ajaxOption don't work as it should be

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

[jQuery UI tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#ajax) options have ajaxOptions.

I have next code:

```
$('#tabs').tabs({
    cookie:{expires:1},
    cache:true,
    ajaxOptions:{
        beforeSend: function(xhr,settings){
            $(".ajax-gif").css("top",$(window).scrollTop()).show();
        },
        error: function(xhr,status,index,anchor){
            $(anchor.hash).html("Couldn't load this tab.");
        },
        complete: function(xhr,textStatus){
            $(".ajax-gif").hide();
        }
    }
});
```

But ajax-gif doesn't show up.

The same code in jQuery ajaxSetup (without jQuery UI) works perfect for usual ajax requests (not in ui tabs). Where did I mistake?

Thanks!

**clarification**

Usual ajax requests use POST form and tabs use GET form.

Comment: ajaxOptions option is only available up to jQuery Ui Tabs 1.8, you can see at http://api.jqueryui.com/1.8/tabs.

Answer (score 1):

What version of jQuery UI tabs are you using? ajaxOptions option is only available up to version 1.8, you can see at http://api.jqueryui.com/1.8/tabs.

For current version (1.11) you would use beforeLoad property. Like this:

```
$('#tabs').tabs({
    beforeLoad: function (event, ui) {

        $(".ajax-gif").css("top",$(window).scrollTop()).show();

        ui.jqXHR.complete(function(data) {
            $(".ajax-gif").hide();
        });

        ui.jqXHR.error(function(data) {
            $(anchor.hash).html("Couldn't load this tab.");
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found solution:

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function(){
    $(".ajax-gif").css("top",$(window).scrollTop()).show();
});
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
    $(".ajax-gif").hide();
});
```